# Frase hecha "Meterse en territorio comanche"

Tags: frases-hechas

Cual es el origen de la frase hecha "meterse en territorio comanche".

Ejemplo:

- "Las modelos cobran por desfile más dinero que los hombres, pero no quiero meterme en territorio comanche pues el feminismo no tolera el debate."

Su significado quiere decir que es un entorno delicado o un tema delicado. Donde hay que andar con precaución dado que puedes salir malparado. Puede ser metafórico o no.

- "Si entras en el Bronx ves con cuidado, es territorio comanche."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como han indicado los compañeros y como arroja una somera búsqueda en Google, Arturo Pérez-Reverte tituló así [un libro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorio_comanche) que narra algunas de sus experiencias como reportero de guerra.

Pero no creo que él acuñara exactamente el término. El concepto está tomado de los westerns clásicos. No he encontrado referencia a ninguna película explícita pero Reverte es un reconocido amante del género. Incluso hay una que se titula exactamente así: [Comanche Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comanche_Territory_(1950_film)) (1950, distribuida como Orgullo Comanche en España). Probablemente en esa o en alguna otra haya una escena donde la caballería o una caravana de carretas llegue a algún punto y alguien advierta: "Cuidado ahora, estamos atravesando territorio comanche". La advertencia indica que se está atravesando un territorio hostil donde pueden acaecer peligros inesperados en cualquier momento. Cualquier conocedor de este género puede emplear la misma metáfora.

Se puede sustituir la palabra comanche por cualquier otra tribu, como apache o cherokee, e incluso por el genérico "índio".

Como atestigua otra película, [Fort Apache, The Bronx](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Apache,_The_Bronx) (1981), el fenómeno no se reduce al español. En dicha película se homenajeaba también a los westerns en el título, donde se asimila una comisaría con un puesto de avanzada (Fort / Fuerte) en territorio hostil rodeado de enemigos.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la frase es de un libro por Arturo Pérez-Reverte llamada "Territorio Comanche." El libro es sobre una guerra que era muy peligrosa.
https://www.lecturalia.com/libro/81/territorio-comanche
La frase probablemente vino de ese libro.

> Los comanches (en idioma comanche, nʉmʉnʉʉ) son una tribu amerindia nativa de la Comanchería, territorio histórico que comprendería el noroeste de Texas y las áreas adyacentes del este de Nuevo México, sudeste de Colorado, suroeste de Kansas, oeste de Oklahoma y norte de Chihuahua. Se calcula que su población máxima ascendió a 45 000 personas. Hoy, la Nación Comanche está constituida aproximadamente por 17 000 personas; cerca de la mitad reside en Oklahoma, principalmente en Lawton, y el resto en Texas, California y Nuevo México. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comanche_%28etnia%29#

Answer (score 1):

Meterse en territorio comanche es como si el instinto te dijera que parases y dieses media vuelta. Es como decir "mejor no meterse en ese tema" o "mejor no meterse por ahí" dando a entender que puede llegar a ser peligroso.

La palabra 'comanche', significaba enemigo y se asociaba a aquella etnia amerindia que cazaba bisontes. Fue rescatada en 1994 por Arturo Pérez Reverte, para titular su 'Territorio comanche', autobiografía sobre el reporterismo de guerra. Con esa expresión señalaba el lugar donde era mejor pegar la vuelta.

No sé si te sirve mi ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Todas las explicaciones tienen sentido. Hoy en día ,¿sigue siendo una expresión aceptable? ¿ o si es conocida como algo histórico?Quiero preguntar dado que en inglés esos tipos de frases están en desuso. Pués, no siempre supongo. La realidad es que no puedo pensar en demasiadas pero al hablar de nativos de alguna forma despectiva suena mal. Quizás la frase no sea muy mala,no estoy segura,pero imagino que hay la connotación de peligro. También, hay que reconocer las injusticias contra los indígenos.

Comment: A pesar de que de acuerdo en general contigo, esto es más un comentario que una respuesta real.

Comment: @PeterM Sí, tiene usted razón,es más un comentario. La verdad es que a veces utilizo un ordenador viejo y por una razón u otro el botón para''comentarios'' no funciona.Por eso,utilizo ''respuesta'' aunque no es correcto hacerlo.Lo siento! Por lo tanto, creo que mi contenido contribuye algo a la discusión.

Comment: ¿Quizás necesites hacer otra pregunta sobre frases que no suenan bien en el siglo 21?  Otra que sé es "No hay moros en la costa".   Pero no sé si es una pregunta de idioma o sociedad.

Comment: Vale. Sí, es un ejemplo,gracias

Comment: He formulado aquí la pregunta. No hagan valoraciones subjetivas. Busquen respuesta.
https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/42998/cuando-una-frase-hecha-es-pol%c3%adticamente-incorrecta