# ¿Cuando una frase hecha es políticamente incorrecta?

Tags: frases-hechas

Durante las últimas décadas, han aparecido colectivos que argumentan sentirse ofendidos por ciertas frases hechas. A veces, simple desconocimiento de su origen.

En cualquier caso, ¿cuándo una frase es políticamente incorrecta?

- ¿Lo define la RAE?
- ¿Lo decide la sociedad?
- ¿Lo decide el colectivo animalista en defensa del mono, del burro y del ganso?

Algunos ejemplos de estas frases podrían ser:

- No hay moros en la costa
- Ser el último mono
- Dar palos de ciego
- Entrar en territorio comanche
- Los hombres no lloran
- Hacer el ganso

PD: Es una pregunta. No respondan con opiniones o valoraciones personales.

Comment: La pregunta es interesante, aunque supera la cuestion linguistica y no estoy seguro de si corresponda (o alcance a) contestarse aquí, porque la definicion de correccion (o incorreccion) politica es proclive a diferencias en los que no hay autoridades aceptadas. Supone el reconocimiento difícil de que existen conflictos, susceptibilidades y derechos (percibidos) y/o efectivamente vulnerados y que están en tensión interpretaciones dañosas de ciertas personas o colectivos.

Comment: Se puede ver esa dificultad leyendo el  contexto cultural, ideológico, político y religioso del término en esta entrada de Wikipedia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correcci%C3%B3n_pol%C3%ADtica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La RAE tiene una opinión clara al respecto. El director de la RAE [dijo lo siguiente en 2018](https://www.rae.es/noticia/dario-villanueva-la-correccion-politica-es-una-nueva-forma-de-censura):

> «La corrección política —ha comenzado señalando en su ponencia Darío Villanueva— es una nueva forma de censura. Una censura perversa, para la que no estábamos preparados, pues no la ejerce el Estado, el Gobierno, el Partido o la Iglesia, sino fragmentos difusos de lo que denominamos sociedad civil».

El artículo es más largo y desarrolla el tema más a fondo. En resumen, la "corrección política" de una expresión no está definida universalmente sino que es definida de manera distinta por distintos fragmentos de la sociedad. La RAE no quiere dejarse censurar y no va a eliminar términos del diccionario solo porque algún colectivo se sienta ofendido.

Comment: Bien, esa es la entendible opinion de neutralidad de la RAE, pero no contesta la pregunta (más amplia) de si exista posibilidad de definir cuando algún discurso (de odio, racismo, negacionista del holocausto, etc)  contraríe consensos sociales mayoritarios sobre lo que se pueda alguien expresar abiertamente.

Comment: +1 para wimi por el hallazgo. ipp, no creo que sea una cuestión de neutralidad, sino de defensa de la lengua. A lo sumo, el diccionario podrá agregar calificaciones como "peyorativo", "tabú", "vulgar", etc. Pero si el término existe y se usa, no puede dejar de incluirse. Hacerlo sería como recortar la lengua.

Comment: Si,,hay peligro de recortar la lengua y hay peligro de ofender.Las autoridades linguísticas últimamente solo pueden avisar de uso vulgar,pejorativo etc. En concreto, depende de la gente de pie que va a decidir el uso o desuso de una frase o palabras históricas de sus idiomas en el porvenir.Es un hecho innegable.

Comment: Claro, se entiende totalmente el argumento de la no censura "de palabras". El asunto es que aquí se preguntó algo distinto,  la existencias de "frases hechas", que si pueden tener condena social y representar amenazas a los derechos de etnias o colectivos, ej "neg__s / git_s / ju_s / zur_s/ etc de mierda: hay q matarlos a todos")

Comment: Una cosa es una frase hecha y otra es la libre combinación de palabras. "de mierda" es una frase hecha que se puede agregar a cualquier sustantivo: libro de mierda, colegio de mierda, país de mierda, etc. "Trabajar como un negro" y 
 "trabajar como un esclavo" sí serían frases hechas como "dormir como un tronco" o "dormir como un lirón".

Comment: El equivalente''trabajar como un negro'' es muy malsonante y ofensivo en inglés. Me sorprende  mucho que siga existiendo en catellano. Creo que la palabra,decimos ''THE N word'' está casi prohibida en inglés pero ,en cambio, muchos negros sí la utiliza. Es algo muy curioso. Para mi,en inglés es despectivo y no soportamos el uso en inglés.

Comment: @Bluelion7 "negro" es una palabra española que de toda la vida ha significado un color (no hay otra forma de decir ese color). Que los anglosajones hayan decidido convertir esa palabra española en un pecado capital es frustrante, porque a veces ha llevado a malentendidos (incluida suspensión laboral) con personas que solo estaban hablando su lengua materna: https://www.theguardian.com/football/2021/mar/08/uefa-suspends-fourth-official-accused-of-racism-during-psg-v-istanbul-basaksehir

Comment: @Bluelion7 por supuesto, la expresión "trabajar como un negro" es ofensiva, de eso no cabe duda. Pero la palabra "negro" en sí es un color y los anglosajones no tienen ningún derecho a prohibírnosla.

Comment: No es que nosotros queremos prohibírsela. Es que es quivalente a ''black person'' en inglés que es perfecto. Ahora, entiendo que en espanol igual que en inglés la frase ''trabajar como un negro'' es ofensiva.

Comment: @ipp la pregunta dice "no respondan con opiniones o valoraciones personales" y aquí doy la respuesta de la RAE. Claramente, la corrección política (como todo lo político) depende de la opinión de cada persona. No hay muchas más fuentes que se puedan citar para eso...

Comment: @wimi. Sí, entiendo que se puede maltraducir algo de espanol a inglés que no es intencional de ofender.Eso es una pena. Hay que pretender de entender más la etimología o el sentido natural de cada idioma.Y es porque estámos aqui para entender más.

Answer (score 1):

No existe normativa, ente ni institución capaz de evaluar unívocamente cuando una frase es políticamente correcta. Y si la hubiera, no estaría relacionada con la lingüística, sino con la justicia.

**Análisis**

Asumiendo corrección política como "*las políticas o las medidas destinadas a evitar ofender o poner en desventaja a personas de grupos particulares de la sociedad.*" [Referencia](https://web.archive.org/web/20240120001043/https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correcci%C3%B3n_pol%C3%ADtica)

A entidades como RAE o Instituto Cervantes no les corresponde evaluar si una frase puede ofender a alguien o no. Mucho menos eliminarlas, cuando son frases hechas aceptadas y usadas, sin ánimo de ofender a nadie, sino de transmitir un mensaje (e.g. "estás haciendo trabajo de chinos" es lo mismo que decir "estás haciendo un trabajo laborioso"). A ellos no corresponden peticiones como [esta](https://web.archive.org/web/20240116054213/https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2013/01/130123_cultura_lenguaje_racista_uruguay_lav) pues forzar cambios en la lengua, no cambiará ni la lengua, ni la bondad tras las personas que la usan. Es un fenómeno ampliamente estudiado [ver](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/marzo_12/13032012_01.htm).

- la RAE tienen, entre sus muchas funciones, la de mantener un diccionario actualizado representando la realidad de la lengua española. Su función no es regular si las frases pueden ofender a alguien, sino describir el significado de esas frases hechas.
- Instituciones, como el Instituto Cervantes, se encargan de enseñar la lengua española. Incluyendo sus refranes o frases hechas aceptadas en la lengua española con el objetivo de que cuando las encuentren en literatura, cine o debate puedan entenderlas.

Sin embargo, desde el punto de vista jurídico, el [Artículo 208 del Código Penal](https://www.conceptosjuridicos.com/codigo-penal-articulo-208/) dice que:

"*Es injuria la acción o expresión que lesionan la dignidad de otra persona, menoscabando su fama o atentando contra su propia estimación.*"

Describiendo la ofensa como un hecho castigado:

- Injurias leves: de 3 a 7 meses de multa.
- Injurias graves (con agravante de publicidad): de 6 a 14 meses de multa.

En consecuencia, se puede deducir que la justicia española es capaz de evaluar una ofensa y, si procede, castigarla.

**Debate**

La justicia puede evaluar una ofensa y, si procede, castigarla. Pero aún sabiendo que puede juzgar ofensas, no dispone de definición ni normativa para evaluar y regular las injurias con propósito de "evitar ofender o poner en desventaja a personas de grupos particulares de la sociedad". Y dada la riqueza de la lengua, resulta imposible definir de manera axiomática cuando una palabra o frase hecha resulta una injuria. Aunque se conozcan el contexto, el emisor, el receptor y el mensaje, no es viable. Existen factores como el tono o el sarcasmo que quedan lejos de ser axiomáticamente representables por un texto jurídico.

**Referencias**

"Es decir, ¿hablar de otra forma nos va a llevar a pensar de otra forma, a reestructurar un pensamiento y una sensibilidad conformados por siglos y siglos de cultura?" [Referencia](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/noviembre_98/20111998_01.htm)

"el filosófico y metafísico «ser o nos ser» que tanto preocupaba a nuestros antepasados ha quedado reducido a un simple y filológico «ser o no ser políticamente correcto» que tanto preocupa a nuestras apariencias." [Referencia](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/marzo_11/14032011_02.htm)

"la polémica sobre el sexismo en el lenguaje, que llega a ser dura e hiriente, se basa en dos errores de principio. El primero: que podemos cambiar la sociedad cambiando la lengua. El segundo: que la lengua es un solo «bloque»." [Referencia](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/marzo_12/13032012_01.htm)